# Change class of list item based on position on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my [site](http://theiamzone.com/kyle_hagler/portfolio-site/index.php), I have a one-page navigation menu. When I click on a link, the page scrolls down to the respective section.
I'm using `magicline jquery`, that sets the hovered list item's class to "current", in order to achieve the moving underline effect.

However, I also need to set `li`'s class to "current" when the user is viewing the corresponding section of the page. I would just make a click event, but of course this wouldn't work if the user scrolled down without clicking, or scrolled up or down to a different section afterwards.

Here's what I've tried so far, with no success. Any ideas?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top ogNav">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <a class="brand" href="index.php">Kyle Hagler</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse nav-wrap">


        <ul class="nav pull-right" id="topnav">
          <li id="homeLink" class="current"><a id="home" href="javascript:;" class="first">Home</a></li>
          <li id="workLink"><a href="#recent">Work</a></li>
          <li id="aboutLink"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li id="contactLink"><a class="last" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    var recent = $('#recent').offset().top; // Get the position of the recent section
    var about = $('#about').offset().top; // Get the position of the about section
    var contact = $('#contact').offset().top; // Get the position of the contact section

     $(window).scroll(function(){ // Window on scroll
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // Get the position of the scroll

            if(scroll > recent) {
                $('#topnav li').removeClass();
                $('#workLink').addClass('current'); 
            }

            if(scroll > about) {
                $('#topnav li').removeClass();
                $('#aboutLink').addClass('current');
            }   

            if(scroll > contact) { // if scroll is greater than contact position then modify the menu
                $('#topnav li').removeClass();
                $('#contactLink').addClass('current');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Always post the relevant code and markup *in the question itself*, don't just link. You can't expect people to follow random links to help you, and external links rot. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily like this

```
var about = $('#about').offset().top; // Get the position of the about section
var contact = $('#contact').offset().top; // Get the position of the contact section

$(window).scroll(function(){ // Window on scroll
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // Get the position of the scroll
    if(scroll > contact) { // if scroll is greater than contact position then modify the menu
        // Change menu to contact
    if(scroll > about) {
       // Change menu to about 
    }
});
```

Comment: this looks right to me too, but for some reason not working

Comment: well, you need to change the menu class or something

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Bootstrap Scrollspy http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy and maybe you can found some others scripts that could be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a setInterval that adjusts it.  In the function you would test which point your viewing is closest to.